# Entity Framework: Code First: Why Relational/Association objects are not being saved while updating?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, code-first

I am from PHP background; now working on a project using ASP.NET MVC4. I am working using Entity Framework as Code First. I was trying to save an object **Item** with 2 **User** object as **CreatedBy** and **ModifiedBy**.

Here is my models:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public virtual User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Item:BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class User //: BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping class:

```
public class ItemMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Item>
{
    public ItemMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(I => I.Id); // I is arbitary varaiable which represent Item ... It is known as lamda expression ... similar to the anonymous method
        this.Property(I => I.Name)
                            .IsRequired()
                            .HasMaxLength(50);
        this.HasOptional(I => I.CreatedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(I => I.CreatedBy.Id);
        this.HasOptional(I => I.ModifiedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(I => I.ModifiedBy.Id);
    }
}
```

DB Context:

```
public class InventoryContext:DbContext
{
    public InventoryContext()
        : base("InventoryContext")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

Item Controller Create and Edit (Save sections) only:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Item item)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(1);
            item.CreatedBy = user;
            db.Items.Add(item);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(item);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Item item)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(2);
            item.CreatedBy = user; // just for test to see any relational object updates
            item.ModifiedBy = user;
            db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(item);
    }
```

This is the part of test code I am using to solve the problem. Now **User** saves properly during **Create**, but not during **Edit**. All other values are updates during the **Edit**, but not the relational objects **User**; **CreatedBy** and **ModifiedBy**

Would you please help me to solve it and let me know what exactly happening here in my code?

Thank you
Sadi

Comment: Have you checked `if(ModelState.IsValid)` *is* `true` in Edit method?

Comment: Do you register `ItemMap` in `OnModelCreating`? I don't think so, because it has an issue. You can't express the foreign key as `I.CreatedBy.Id`. The property must be a property of `Item` itself (like `int CreatedById`) _or_ you must remove the `HasForeignKey` clause altogether. Resolve this issue first and then come back if the problem still occurs.

Comment: @Kaf Yes, I have debug it it successfully save all other value except the USER

Comment: @GertArnold In the main project it does, but not in the sample test project. Okay, let me check if it works after register in OnModelCreating. Though it works correctly during Insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it. Here is the solution with comments for clarrification

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Item item)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(2); // find the user; later implement the session
        db.Items.Attach(item);  // attach item manually to track changes of Relational object of item
        db.Entry(item).Reference(i => i.ModifiedBy).Load();  // load the User object of item property ModifiedBy; since it is virtual aka lazy loading
        item.ModifiedBy = user; // assing user to ModifiedBy
        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(item);
}
```

But it has a little problem. If I change the **user**; then the changes will be saved in the user object/table though I do not want to save it.